# Asynchronous loading data issue AngularJS and Firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I am having difficulties loading data from Firebase into my AngularJS factory and thus controllers.

Basically I have the following **factory**:

```
.factory('usersList', ['fbutil', function(fbutil) {
   return {
    all: function() {
           return fbutil.syncArray('users');
    },
    get: function(userId) {

        fbutil.syncArray('users').then( function(result) {

            window.alert(result.length) // FIRST ALERT

            var x = 0;

            for (var i = 0, len = result.length; i < len; i++) {

                if (result[i].uid == userId) {
                window.alert("fount id") // SECOND ALERT
                x = i;
                } else {
                window.alert("nope"); // THIRD ALERT
                }
            }

            return result[x];

        }) // then
    } // get
    } // return
 }]); // usersList
```

And my **controller** looks like:

```
 .controller('OverviewCtrl', ['$scope', 'fbutil', 'usersList', function($scope, fbutil, usersList) {

    $scope.usersList = usersList.all();
    $scope.testUser = usersList.get("simplelogin:29");

    // OTHER CODE

    };
  }])
```

In my HTML file, when I call `{{usersList}}` then it produces the result:

```
[{"color":"#CC0066","email":"a@a.com","name":"Eva","uid":"simplelogin:27"},{"color":"#009933","email":"b@b.com","name":"Semko","uid":"simplelogin:28"},{"color":"#CC0066","email":"c@c.com","name":"Caroline","uid":"simplelogin:29"}]
```

But testUser does not load, just shows `{{tesUser}}` in the index file.

Does anyone know how to handle this correctly? Without using the then(), which in this example also does not work, I figured out from the first alert that the `result.length` equaled 0, which gave me the suggestion that I am dealing with asynchronous loading. That is why I am trying to handle it whit `.then()` but apparently it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle a promise in angularjs the best way it to use defer values, since it allows you to process it before returning the data while keeping everything non blocking. With $http I would process like this :

```
function get(id) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  var url = "anUrlwithid";
  $http.get(url).success(function(data, status) {
        logger.logDebug('Successful GET call to ' + url + '\n, results ' + status + ': ' + data);

           deferred.resolve(function(data){
             //do something to your data then return
           });

      }).error(function(data, status) {
        logger.logDebug('Failed GET call to ' + url + '\n, results ' + status + ': ' + data);
        deferred.reject(data);
      });
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

And to process it in the controller :

```
get(1).then(function(data){//update scope or do something with the data processed});
```

You should be able to use that with your fbutil since it returns a promise I think.
Hope it helps

More details on the Q module here : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

PS: the logger is one of my personal service, just use console.log instead

Comment: Not getting it really. Do you have to inject the $q in the factory and or app?

Comment: Yes, it is one of angular service

Comment: When I insert it, my app does not work anymore. Basically I get a blank screen. I tried: angular.module('myApp.services', ['$q']) and then in my factory: .factory('usersList', ['fbutil', '$q', function(fbutil, $q) { ...

Comment: what does the console say ?

Comment: you don't need to put $q in myApp.services', ['$q'], it is a service like any other already in angular